# Java XML: how to get attribute value as NULL if not present?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Java XML: how to get attribute value as NULL if not present?

```
<foo name="A"/>

elementFoo.getAttribute("value");  // return empty string
```

It returns empty string. Is there a way to get the value as NULL? It is easy to convert it. But we have hundreds of places like this, and it would be great if XML parser support it. Is there a way to configure XML parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `Element#getAttribute` will always return an `empty String` if the attribute does not have a specified or default value.

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97339_01/doc/xml/parser/oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)):

```
public String getAttribute(String name)
...
Returns: The Attr value as a string, or the empty string if that attribute does not have a specified or default value.
```

But you can use `Element#getAttributeNode` instead, it will return `null` if the attribute does not exist.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97339_01/doc/xml/parser/oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement.html#getAttributeNode(java.lang.String)

Later, you can use `Attr#getValue()` to retrieve the value.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97339_01/doc/xml/parser/org.w3c.dom.Attr.html#getValue()